# JavaScript click() function and propagation

Tags: javascript, event-propagation

I'm curious why this simple code does not run indefinitely. After reading Eloquent JavaScript, it says that the immediate nodes will execute first, and then the outer nodes will, in turn, execute their click event listeners. However, the code below only gives these 7 lines as output. It seems as if lines 5 and 6 would fire the click listener on the container again. Perhaps I am not understanding something about propagation. I've tried debugging using Visual Studio and it does not enter the function, but I cannot find a way to determine why this is using the debugger. Thanks for the help.

1. "body clicked"
2. "container clicked"
3. "item clicked"
4. "container clicked"
5. "body clicked"
6. "body clicked"

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const item = document.getElementById("item");
const body = document.getElementById("body");

item.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("item clicked");
});

container.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("container clicked");
  item.click();
});

body.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("body clicked");
  container.click();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}

div.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

 div.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>My website</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="site.css">
    </head>
    <body id="body">body
        <div class="container" id="container">container
            <div class="item" id="item">item</div>
        </div>
        <script src="site.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: programatic `click()` calls don't trigger events. So all you see is the initial `click` *events* triggered by the mouse and it's bubbling, plus the explicit `element.click()` calls

Comment: And, the results will vary depending on what element you click first. I have updated the CSS to differentiate between the body, container and item.

Comment: There is very thorough documentation on the [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) page: [Example of options usage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#example_of_options_usage)

Comment: Okay, so it doesn't trigger events. I thought it would trigger after reading "The click() method simulates a mouse-click on an element...This method can be used to execute a click on an element as if the user manually clicked on it." on w3schools.com.

Comment: *w3schools.com* is a really bad source of information

Answer (score 0):

As @pilchard pointed out in the comments, calling the `click()` method of an element will only invoke that element's `click` event handling function (no different than directly calling the function by its name), but it won't trigger an actual `click` event.

Below, I've commented out those calls and you are left with being able to clearly see that a mouse `click` does trigger the event and how that event will bubble up through the clicked element's ancestor elements.

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const item = document.getElementById("item");
const body = document.getElementById("body");

item.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("item clicked");
});

container.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("container clicked");
  //item.click();
});

body.addEventListener("click", function () {
  console.log("body clicked");
  //container.click();
});
```

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
}

div.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: aqua;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

 div.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">body
  <div class="container" id="container">container
     <div class="item" id="item">item</div>
  </div>
</body>
```